# ListView и SimpleCursorAdapter отобразить не только текст и не весь текст

Tags: java, android, listview, cursor, android-sqlite

Здравствуйте!
Заполняю listView из БД SQLite следующим образом:

```
    SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_ONE, null, null, null, null, null, null);

    String[] from = new String[]{DBHelper.COLUMN_ONE, DBHelper.COLUMN_TWO};

    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2};

    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, cursor, from, to, 0);

    listView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

**Возник вопрос.** Допустим, у меня есть столбец COLUMN_ONE, в котором может быть какой-то текст, либо "Отсутствует". Так вот, как сделать так, чтобы если в COLUMN_ONE "Отсутствует", то в R.id.textView1 не отображается ничего (""), а не "Отсутствует"?

**Вопрос номер два.** COLUMN_TWO типа integer. На R.layout.list_item, кроме textView1 имеется imageView. Как по цифре отобразить картинку в элементе списка? Например, если цифра 0, то картинка будет одна, если 1, то другая и т.д.

Comment: Храните в БД пустую строку вместо "отсутствует" или в `bindView()` адаптера проверяйте на содержимое строки и если = "отсутствует" в TextView биндите пустую строку. По второму - храните не абстрактные числа, а ID картинки, которую надо отобразить, потом по этому ID биндите в виджет картинку. Условие у вас и не будет выполняться, потому что в базе левые числа, а сравнение идет с ID картинки

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно нашли решение проблемы в вопросе, нужно оформить его ответом, а не писать его в вопросе

Comment: @pavlofff, ну как самостоятельно, вы же написали про bindView, я загуглил, нашел пример и изменил его под свои нужды. Коммент я пометил как добавляющий полезную информацию, а при попытке ответить на свой вопрос получил "Оставьте комментарий, если Вы хотите прокомментировать ответ. **Отредактируйте свой вопрос, если Вы хотите добавить дополнительную информацию.**" Т.е. все правильно.

Comment: Нажмите "ответить на свой вопрос" и разместите ответ там. В вопросе не должно быть решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделал через bindView

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter
{
    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags)
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        String one = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ONE));
        int two = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_TWO));

        if (dateStart.equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.NotSet)))
            text.setText("");
        else
            text.setText(one);

        if (two == 1)
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico1);
        else
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ico2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо создать свой класс адаптера, унаследованный от `SimpleCursorAdapter` и в нем прописать свою реализацию вывода информации в `View` компоненты. Примерно вот так:

```
public class MySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public MySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(value) == 0) v.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        if (Integer.parseInt(value) == 1) v.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
    }

    @Override
    public void setViewText(TextView v, String text) {

        if (text.equals("Отсутствует") v.setText("");
    }

}
```

Comment: А как быть с тем, что у меня list_item это отдельный xml, а `imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);` происходит в классе MainActivity. Соответственно, если я вызываю `cursorAdapter.setViewImage(imageView, "0");`, то он не находит такой id и выводит NullPointerException?

Comment: @badadin тебе не надо вызывать самому метод `setViewImage`. Нужно просто в этой строке `int[] to = new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2};`, поменять `R.id.textView2`, на `R.id.imageView1`, который должен находится в разметке list_item. То есть метод `setViewImage` вызывается когда по ид находится компонент `ImageView`, а в value будет передаваться значение из базы данных в колонке COLUMN_TWO, указанной в массиве from.

Comment: @pavlofff Мне все-таки интересно, а чем хуже `setViewImage` и `setViewText`, чем `bindView` ?

Comment: @MaksimPonomarev Есть устоявшаяся практика, что наполнение айтема контентом происходит в методе `bindView()`. Вообще, указанные вами методы [вызывает сам `bindView()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.java#135) при реализации биндинга по дефолту. Реализуя свою логику переопределением `bindView()` мы имеем большую свободу в реализации задуманного. Я вот, до вашего ответа, ни разу не встречал такой способ биндить в айтем и почему этот способ не популярен мне искать лень, но причины ,наверное, есть.

Comment: Думаю, эти методы работают только с дефолтной разметкой айтема, потому и не популярны, но разбираться мне лень.

Comment: Все, теперь понял, спасибо за ответ.